# How to only view tweets that have a specific hashtag

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am creating an app that I want to show tweets on the main ViewController that all have a particular hashtag in them. I already have STTwitter set up and it gets things from twitter but how do I filter for a hashtag? I want to do this without being limited to one username. I want this to work so any person that has posted a tweet with a certain hashtag will populate my view. Is there a way to run a query for hashtags in STTwitter?

If not with STTwitter, what else should I be using? All the apis that I look at don't mention anything about being able to search for particular hashtags.

Any ideas here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to run a query for hashtags in STTwitter?

Yes! Use the following method on STTwitterAPI:

```
[_twitter postStatusesFilterKeyword:@"#Apple"
                         tweetBlock:^(NSDictionary *tweet) {
                           //
                       } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                           //
                       }];
```

Also, the OS X demo project provides a GUI to test that:

[image]

Comment: I am getting the stream is empty response for above Do you have idea regarding this error ?